# Extend standard UI5 control

Tags: sapui5

I want to add an additional text property to sap.ui.unified.MenuItem. It currently has only one text property.

I am trying the following

```
        sap.ui.unified.MenuItem.extend("ExtendedMenuItem",{
            metadata:{
                properties:{
                    SetText : {type: "string"}

                },
                aggregations: {
                    _SecondText : {type: "sap.ui.commons.Label", multiple : false, visibility: "public"}
                }
            },
            init: function(){
                var oSecondText = new sap.ui.commons.Label("TL",{
                    text: this.SetText
                });
                this.addAggregation("_SecondText",oSecondText);
            },
            renderer:"sap.ui.unified.MenuItemRenderer"
        });

        var oTestCopy = new ExtendedMenuItem("TC",{
            text: "TEST COPY",
            SetText: "CTRL+TEST"
        });
```

but the second text property is not being displayed.
What can i do to add a second text property to a standard UI5 control ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html) is an example from the official documentation of Custom Controllers. You have to implement the renderer itself to place the new m.Label element on the UI. In the renderer, you can operate with standard HTML elements. For more details, check the linked source.